# Google Cloud TCP Timeouts (ETIMEDOUT)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

I'm having the following issue:

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 209.85.234.27:25
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1159:16) {
```

when running the following code on GCP (both Cloud Functions and Cloud Run fail):

```js
const verifier = require('email-verify')
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

/**
 * Verify an email address
 */

app.post('/verify', async (request, response, _next) => {
  const email = request.query.email
  console.log(`Verifying ${email}`)

  const isValid = await new Promise(function (resolve, _reject) {
    if (!email || typeof email !== 'string') {
      return resolve(false)
    }

    verifier.verify(email, function (err, info) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err)
        return resolve(false)
      }

      return resolve(info.success)
    })
  })

  response.json({ valid: isValid, email: typeof email === 'string' ? email : '' })
})

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

I feel like GCP timeouts when trying to connect to distant servers, but I don't find any resource online to help me debug this. Does anyone already got this kind of issue?

Comment: Does the target server filter the inbound connection? Did you check the logs?

Comment: Thanks Guillaume. Looks like GCP blocks the TCP Port 25. Hence the issue I'm facing.

Comment: Oh, yes, port 25 is blocked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we look at the error message, we see that it is attempting to connect to an external service at port 25.  Google *always* blocks outbound requests to port 25.  You can find this documented and relevant alternatives at this page:

[Sending email from an instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail)

In addition, [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=gcp+blocks+port+25+site:stackoverflow.com) is a good search query (here on StackOverflow) for similar questions and answers.

Comment: Do you know if we can ask Google to remove such limitation? I’ve just seen that AWS has a form to request just that. If not, any idea of a Cloud provider that would accept requesting port 25?

Comment: Yes ... it is possible to remove the restriction and whitelist your project to allow outbound on port 25.  You should raise a support ticket to request such.  It appears that the request can take 3 weeks or more to become effective.  You must have a paid account at GCP.  Free accounts are never approved.  When you request the unblocking your account will be reviewed and then you may be contacted by the support specialist for additional questions.