# Google Cloud Run Error: connect ETIMEDOUT at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect

Tags: express, google-cloud-platform, react-redux, sendgrid, google-cloud-run

I have a problem with Google Cloud Run and Sendgrid, when I try to send an email using Sendgrid api after a few minutes I receive this error: `Error: connect ETIMEDOUT at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect`, I understand that this is not an error from Sendgrid but I'm not sure, I don't know if maybe I have something wrong in the Sendgrid settings or it's something about my firewall.

This is my api config:

```
            import sgMail from "@sendgrid/mail";

            sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
            const msg = {
                to: `${user.email}`,
                from: 'correo@cool.org.mx', // Use the email address or domain you verified above
                subject: 'Recuperación de contraseña',
                html: `Hola`
            };
    
            try {
                await sgMail.send(msg);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
                if (error.response) {
                    res.status(500).json({ msg: error.response.body })
                }
            }
```

I have my api key and my account in Sendgrid but I don't understand why I'm getting this error: `Error: connect ETIMEDOUT at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect`

Comment: Can you check if you are using unsupported ports as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70489959/18265570) and also verify that you have configured firewall for custom port as mentioned in the [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail#email_custom_port)

Comment: @RoopaM actually I already checked both. For example, I added two new rules to my firewall. One is just for TCP port 2525, and the other one is for TCP port 587. According to the SendGrid documentation, ports 587 and 443 should be open, but my new rules don't seem to be working.

Comment: Since the Timeout errors were originated from Cloud NAT **Dropped** packets, Increase the ports per VM and disable Endpoint independent mapping so the connections from Cloud Run to the outer world could be done more efficiently.

Comment: @VeeraNagireddy thanks for your answer. Well, I'm really a noob at using Google Cloud, so I didn't have a Cloud NAT. But now I have created one, and everything works.

Comment: @Enrique Espinosa, Glad to hear everything works after creating Cloud NAT. Same provided as an answer. Feel free to Accept and upvote the answer for better community visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Timeout errors were originated from **Cloud NAT Dropped packets**, Increase the ports per VM and disable Endpoint independent mapping so the connections from Cloud Run to the outer world could be done more efficiently.

If you didn't have a Cloud NAT, create one, which will resolve your issue.